# Error Unresolved reference: LoadAnimation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I leave the code here below to know what is happening, what is the error, I am trying to get an animation there, I am following a tutorial in java but I am doing it in kotlin
there they have what matters for the class, and the error is in the animationUtilitis part, I don't know if it is the correct way to do it in kotlin:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
import com.yr.iolite.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_splash.*

class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    var bg: ImageView? = null
    var logo: ImageView? = null
    var penguin: LottieAnimationView? = null
    var anim: Animation? = null
    //private val viewPager : ViewPager? = null
    private var pagerAdapter : ScreenSliderPagerAdapter? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        inicializar()


    }
    private fun inicializar()
    {
        bg = findViewById(R.id.bg_snow_splash)
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo_splash)
        penguin = findViewById(R.id.penguin_splash)

        val viewPager : ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.swipe_screen)
        pagerAdapter = ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, R.anim.swipe_screen_anim)
        viewPager.startAnimation(anim)
        bg_snow_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(-1600f)
        }
        logo_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(-1400f)
        }
        penguin_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(1400f)
        }
    }
    private class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter (fm : FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm)
    {
        val NUM_TABS = 3
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment
        {
            return when (position)
            {
                0 -> SwipeFragement1()
                1 -> SwipeFragement2()
                else -> SwipeFragement3()
            }
        }
        override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_TABS
    }
}
```

Here I also leave the error that appears in a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your

```
 anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, R.anim.swipe_screen_anim)
```

to this

```
 anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.swipe_screen_anim)
```

Comment: Your problem and answer statements are same.